# Dúvidas sobre utilização de AppBar + Toolbar + Fragment - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragment

Olá,

tenho conhecimento prévio de **Java** mas comecei agora a programação para mobile no *Android Studio*, alguém saberia me dizer se há alguma forma de utilizar **AppBar + Toolbar** (por questão de design mesmo, o **BottomNavigation** eu achei muito feio e pouco customizável), como menu flutuante, junto com **Fragments**?

Já pensei em algumas formas, e estava utilizando o **setOnClickListener** mas não consigo achar uma forma de alternar o *fragment*. Também já tentei utilizar o **NavigationUI** mas foi sem sucesso, provavelmente estou deixando de perceber algo. Vou deixar aqui minha **MainActivity.java** e minha **activiy_main.xml** para que dê um exemplo melhor do que eu gostaria de fazer.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:liftOnScroll="true">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow_bottombar_main"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainNavigation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/mainTitle"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gilroy_bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:textColor="#AA000000"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/popularNavigation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/popularsTitle"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gilroy_bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:textColor="#AA000000"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarLayout bottomBar;
    private Toolbar toolbarMain;
    private TextView mainNavigation;
    private TextView popularNavigation;
    private NavController navController;
    private MainFragment mainFragment;
    private PopularsFragment popularsFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomBar = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        toolbarMain = findViewById(R.id.toolbarMain);
        mainNavigation = findViewById(R.id.mainNavigation);
        popularNavigation = findViewById(R.id.popularNavigation);
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        popularsFragment = new PopularsFragment();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbarMain, navController);

        onOptionsItemSelected();

    }



    public void eventOnClickMenuBottom() {
        mainNavigation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                navController = Navigation.findNavController(mainFragment.getActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment);
            }
        });

        popularNavigation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                navController = Navigation.findNavController(popularsFragment.getActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Minha ideia era fazer o **onClick** de cada **TextView** mudar a *activity* do **navController**, mas não rolou.

Enfim, obrigado pela atenção quem leu e agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: o que acha de usar tablayout e viewpager?

Comment: Fui avisado sobre o ViewPager, consegui implementar ele pro meu código e funciona. Meu problema agora é que eu preciso fazer que botões dentro dos fragmentos mudem o que tá aparecendo na ViewPager, aí tô quebrando a cabeça com isso agora. Mas sim, sua dica estava certíssima, a melhor forma de fazer o que eu queria era com ViewPager. Agradeço!

Comment: Você pode tentar implementar um listener no adapter do ViewPager, para os fragments se comunicarem com ele, qualquer coisa coloque oque conseguiu fazer na atualização da sua resposta, e amanhã tento te ajudar mais.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa resposta, por favor!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600229/go-to-next-page-in-viewpager/36601047#36601047

Comment: Obrigado aos dois (iria marcar ambos, mas acabei de perceber que não é permitido), as respostas ajudaram bastante. Ontem eu implementei esse método que o Thiago mandou agora e realmente funciona bem. Consegui fazer o que precisa, agora é partir para outras partes do projeto e ter novas dúvidas... hahahahahahha